# IBM Workload Scheduler: importing thousands of jobs and job streams takes a long time

Tags: import, jobs, workload-scheduler

I'm trying to import a huge number of jobs and job streams (I'm looking at several thousands...) using either composer replace or the datamigrate utility. However, it takes a looong time.... Anyone out there can offer any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers... regarding your question, what have you tried so far? Post some code so others can help

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps: 
 
1. increase the WAS java heap size to 4GB (at least)
2. Change the TIMEOUT property contained in the localopts file related to the TWS component (MDM or FTA) from which you have to perform the import process to a convenient value (so that the timeout does not expire while the import is ongoing.